# Размер шрифта в дереве папок IDE PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.
Подскажите как поменять размер шрифта в дереве папок проекта PHPStorm.
http://joxi.ru/n2YZJ0zUD9R0A6

Владимир

Answer (score 1):

`Settings(Preferences) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`, `Override default fonts`. см. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/appearance.html#d424172e129

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!